# mongosh: How to create ascending date object for every record in a collection?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a small collection with records of the format:

```
db.presentations = 
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "student": "A",
    "presentationDate": {
      "$date": "2023-01-17T00:00:00Z"
    }
  },
{
    "_id": "2",
    "student": "B",
    "presentationDate": {
      "$date": "2023-01-17T00:00:00Z"
    }
  },
...
,
{
    "_id": "26",
    "student": "Z",
    "presentationDate": {
      "$date": "2023-01-17T00:00:00Z"
    }
  },
]
```

Instead of all the `presentationDate`s being the same, I want to set them to an ascending order. So, `student` A's `presentationDate` is 2023-01-17, `student` B's is 2023-01-18, `student` C's is 2023-01-19, and so on.

I've been exploring some functions that could do this, but none really seem to fit what I'm trying to do, eg:

- `$dateAdd`: allows specification of the unit and amount (eg, day, 3) by which to increase a date object, but it must be used as part of an aggregation pipeline. I don't see how to increment by variable amount for each document.
- `forEach()` / `map()`: allows flexibility in function applied to each record, but again, I don't see how to increment by variable (uniformly increasing) amount for each document. I'm also not sure it's possible to edit documents within a forEach?

Put another way, I'm basically trying to iterate through my cursor/collection and update each document, incrementing a global variable on each itereation.

I'm new to mongosh, so any ideas, feedback are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could select the data, iterate over all documents, change the value and save back. You can also do it with an aggregation pipeline like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         sortBy: { student: 1 },
         output: {
            pos: { $documentNumber: {} }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         presentationDate: {
            $dateAdd: {
               startDate: "$presentationDate",
               unit: "day",
               amount: "$pos"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

If you like to modify the data, then use

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, [
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         sortBy: { student: 1 },
         output: { 
            pos: { $documentNumber: {} }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         presentationDate: {
            $dateAdd: {
               startDate: "$presentationDate",
               unit: "day",
               amount: "$pos"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```